# How do I install SQL Server Management Studio 2012 64-bit?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I bought a copy of SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to be able to install SQL Server Management Studio 64-bit from the install disc. I've tried installing and uninstalling several times, and only the 32-bit version shows up. Even the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio folder exists, but not the 64-bit executable. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit SP1 with 16 GB of RAM...

Edit: a little further info... sqlservr.exe is running in 64-bit. Just not ssms.exe...

Comment: I think this was [answered on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/41033/is-there-a-64-bit-version-of-ssms-and-bids-with-sql-server-2008-64-bit)

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I saw that one initially, but still had hope of a 64-bit edition considering that question was regarding SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing. The application itself, like Visual Studio, only ships as a 32-bit application, regardless of the operating system and regardless of the instance(s) you use it with.

Comment: I had hopes there was a 64-bit version available given that Microsoft has that SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio 64-bit download (SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe), plus there were a lot of questions out there on which version to install... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jimmy that is a 32-bit version of Management Studio meant for x64 platforms, not a 64-bit version of Management Studio. The DVD for Developer Edition has both; the download is split up to save on file size.